# FastApi Issue while running server command

Tags: python, fastapi

I am learning FastApi and while running the code `uvicorn main:app --reload` inside app directory on cmd below issue occurs

[image: error]

My folder structure

[image: is this]

I am Stuck in this issue and have no idea what is happening.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do relative import, there's no gain, do absolute import from the root of the package `from app import models`

Comment: Still same issue but saying from app import models
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'